# Join nested relationship as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with my SQL. I am attempting to get the following rows...

| ID | Sender | Code 1 | Code 1 Score | Code 2 | Code 2 Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | AB | 80 | BA | 87 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | CD | 45 | DC | 99 |

The code columns are the hard part. This is the relationships

Conversation -> Messages -> Highlights -> Codes.

- Messages have a conversation_id
- Messages Highlights have a message_id
- Codes have a highlight_id

One conversation has many messages, Each Message has many Highlights, and any highlights have many codes.

```sql
SELECT
        conversations.id,
        CONCAT(senders.first_name, ' ', senders.last_name) as 'Sender Name'
        conversations.created_at AS 'Start Date',
FROM
    conversations
    LEFT JOIN users AS senders ON sender.id = conversations.participant_1
    LEFT JOIN users AS recipient ON recipient.id = conversations.participant_2
GROUP BY
    conversations.name
```

I cannot figure out how to include the codes into the results as columns that a paired (Code 1 Name, Code Score).

The above query works to get the first few columns, but I'd like to join in the codes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to make use of `row_number` to create multiple columns

```
SELECT m.highlight_id, 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END )
FROM
(
SELECT 
b.highlight_id, b.code_name, b.code_score, (CASE WHEN @T = b.highlight_id THEN @RN := @RN + 1 ELSE @RN := 1 END ) AS RN, @T := b.highlight_id
FROM highlights a 
JOIN codes b ON a.highlight_id = b.highlight_id
JOIN (SELECT @T := '', @RN := 0) u
ORDER BY a.highlight_id, b.code_name
) m
GROUP BY m.highlight_id
;
```

If you are using MySQL 8.0, it's simpler

```
SELECT m.highlight_id, 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN m.code_name ELSE '' END ), 
MAX( CASE WHEN RN = 5 THEN m.code_score ELSE '' END )
FROM (
SELECT b.highlight_id, b.code_name, b.code_score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.highlight_id ORDER BY b.code_name) RN
FROM highlights a 
JOIN codes b ON a.highlight_id = b.highlight_id
) m
GROUP BY m.highlight_id
;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to give this a shot. My sql is limited, how would I fit this into my existing sql?

Comment: It's an idea with `highlights JOIN codes` for illustration. You can continue to `JOIN` addtional tables, `JOIN messages ON ... JOIN conversations ON ... LEFT JOIN users ...` And `GROUP BY/PARTITION` part probably needs to amend to fit your requirement too.